# How to find files differing only by extension

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have multiple random `.txt` files, and in the same directory I have nearly-identically-named files like `filename.sql` and `filename.txt`. How would I find those `.sql` and their counterpart `.txt` files without selecting any other `.txt` files? (The intent here is to move them to a separate folder. There is a guaranteed 1:1 relationship between the relevant `.sql` and `.txt` files, meaning that I'm not worried about moving one of the random `.txt` files mentioned initially.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple:

```
$ mv `ls *.sql|sed s/.sql$/.txt/g` dir
```

To see and understand how it works, how the shell expands the line before executing `mv`, start the line with `echo`:

```
$ ls
a.sql b.sql a.txt b.txt c.txt
$ echo mv `ls *.sql|sed s/.sql/.txt/g` dir
mv a.txt b.txt dir
```

Something more "robust" if the file names have spaces (generally not a good idea in Unix, but happens) or you have hundreds of files in the directory:

```
$ for f in *.sql; do mv "$(echo $f|sed s/.sql$/txt/)" dir; done
```

To move the `.sql` files along with the corresponding `.txt` files:

```
$ for f in *.sql; do mv "$f" "$(echo $f|sed s/.sql$/txt/)" dir; done
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you or someone walk me through this? (It's not "simple" to me :) I see that all .sql files are selected and then piped to sed, which somehow substitutes something and then I don't understand.

Comment: Select all .sql files in the current directory, replace `.sql` in their names to `.txt` and move files having resulting names to `dir`

Comment: So once moved to 'dir', all files will have a '.txt' extension...? I think I wasn't clear in my question then. I wish to preserve the extensions.

Comment: To be slightly more robust (i.e. only substitute `.sql` for `.txt` at the end of the filename) use `s/.sql$/.txt/`.  The `g` at the end of the substitution is unnecessary because each filename from `ls` will be on its own line anyway.

Comment: robust? will break if the filename contains a space. ;)

Comment: @verbsintransit `sed` does not modify the filenames at all, it only modifies the output provided by `ls`.  So when `ls` would print `foo.sql`, sed will cause it to instead print `foo.txt`, so that `mv` can move the correct file.

Comment: No, you didn't understand. To see what's happening prepend `echo` to the line and see how shell expands this.

Comment: OK, sorry to bring this back to life, but I tried your setup just now. I see that it does move a.txt and b.txt in the destination directory. But I also want the corresponding a.sql and b.sql files. When I tried basically inverting it: `mv 'ls *.txt|sed s/.txt$/.sql/g' dir` it tried to find the nonexistent c.sql. Advice?

Comment: Just move all .sql files separately

Comment: You want to move all .sql files, right? That's simple: `mv *.sql dir`. Or do you need to do both things in one command???...

Comment: Well. Don't I feel clever. I mean it would be pedagogically nice to do it in one command, but it's not necessary in my current situation.

Comment: Don't worry, happens :)

Answer (score 2):

piokuc's answer works great, but if you get an ***argument list too long*** error (happens if you're moving a lot of files at once), this works as well:

```
ls *.sql | sed s/.sql/.txt/g | xargs -I% mv % /path/to/new/directory
```

Explanation:

1. List all files name ending with `.sql` extension.
2. Replace `.sql` with `.txt` in the filename list (this doesn't rename the files, just operates on the piped input).
3. `xargs`

   - `xargs` is a program that runs other programs. We are going to run the `mv` (move file) command through it.
   - The `-I` option tells `xargs` to run the `mv` command individually for every single file name being passed by `sed`.
   - The `%` refers to actual object/filename being passed to `xargs`, so upon each iteration this is going to be one of the substituted file names.
   - Notice that there are 2 `%`: one is attached next to `-I`, which tells `xargs` to use the ampersand character as a token for a file name. The second occurrence is with `mv`, where the actual (and by now changed) file name gets substituted for the token.

   Esentially, `xargs` is saying, "For each one of the piped-in file names, run `mv NEW_FILE_NAME.txt /path/to/new/directory`."

Comment: +1 yeah, I was just thinking about adding a comment like that. Similarly one could do something like `for f in *.sql; do mv `echo $f|sed s/.sql$/txt/` dir; done`

Comment: can't show it properly with the formatting in a comment, will copy to my answer